# Typescript nested functions with default function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've searched a lot but not found anything that suits to me.
I want to create a custom console logger to my app.

It will only log if is in Dev mode and I want to call it like this:

```
// isDev === true
logger('log') //prints 'log'
logger.error('error') // prints 'error'
// isDev === false
logger('log') // prints nothing
logger.error('error') // prints nothing
```

I've tryed creating this method but the most close I've got is this:

```
function logger(...data: any[]) {

    if(!isDev) return
    console.log(...data)

    return {
        error: console.error(...data)
    }
}
```

When I call it, this happens:

```
// isDev === true
logger('log') // This is ok, prints 'log'
logger('error').error // This is wrong
// prints 'error' twice: One is a normal log and other is the error log
// I want only print the error log
```

and ...

```
// isDev === false
logger('test').error // throws error "Cannot read properties of 'undefined'
```

How should I write this method?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using Object.assing

```
export const logger = Object.assign(
    // here we assign the default call
    // so we can call it with -> logger('log')
    ( ...data: any[] ) => {
        if ( !isDev() ) return
        console.log( ...data )
    }, {
        // here we assing all subfunctions
        // so we can call -> logger.error('error')
        error: ( ...data: any[] ) => {
            if ( !isDev() ) return
            console.error( ...data )
        },
        // or call -> logger.trace('trace')
        trace: ( ...data: any[] ) => {
            if ( !isDev() ) return
            console.trace( ...data )
        },
        // or call -> logger.warn('warn')
        warn: ( ...data: any[] ) => {
            if ( !isDev() ) return
            console.warn( ...data )
        }            
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the fence as to whether or not this is a *good idea*<sup>TM</sup> in the first place, since the confusion in building it is a clear indication that there will be confusion in using it.  Confusion leads to bugs.  Simple may occasionally look *too simple* to the intuitive eye and we want something *clever*, but simple is easy to understand and support.

Having said that...

Maybe something like this?:

```js
function logger(message) {
  if (message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
  return {
    message: msg => console.log(msg),
    error: err => console.error(err)
  }
}

logger('log test 1');
logger().error('error test 1');
logger().message('log test 2');
```

Basically it's a function that conditionally performs a default action if an argument is provided, but also returns an object with functions that perform more specific actions if needed.  In the default usage the returned object can just be ignored.

As a variant you might also only conditionally return, for example:

```js
function logger(message) {
  if (message) {
    console.log(message);
  } else {
    return {
      message: msg => console.log(msg),
      error: err => console.error(err)
    }
  }
}

logger('log test 1');
logger().error('error test 1');
logger().message('log test 2');
```

Same thing, it just prevents accidental double-usage such as:

```
logger('message test').error('error test');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I've ended up using Object.assign. Take a look in the answer for more details